# Storing an ascii lookup table in a file in Python

Tags: python, encoding, escaping, ascii

I have a lookup table hard-coded in python at the moment that looks something like:

```
   lookup = {
       "\x85": u'...', # ...
       "\x91": u"'",
       ...
   }
```

I would like to move the mapping to an external file to make it easier to manage, but have not been able to find a way to store x-escaped character codes and read them back in. Instead of '\x85', I end up with '\x85'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you format the file like so:

```
{
       "\x85": u'...',
       "\x91": u"'"
}
```

Then you can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to get the lookup table into your program:

```
In [10]: ast.literal_eval(open('lookup.txt').read())
Out[10]: {'\x85': u'...', '\x91': u"'"}
```

If you want to employ a custom format, you could just store the hex ASCII codes for the keys (e.g. `85`, `91` etc), and convert them while reading:

```
In [17]: chr(int('91', 16))
Out[17]: '\x91'
```

Comment: Nice trick! :) Just make sure that lookup.txt only comes from trusted sourced.

Comment: @MariaZverina No need. `literal_eval()` is explicitly defined as safe to use on any data in the docs. (In stark contrast to `eval()`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That should work out pretty well. The later solution is what I was originally thinking and is also good to know.